# React throws thousands of TypeError any time I do something in the app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Everytime I do something in the app (only when started with npm start) the console throws thousands of Typerror messages:
[image]

This does not happen when I build the app...
Navigating through the backend.bundle file has no sense since it is minified and there is no _owner property in my code unless that autogenerated file 678.da0c3d...:
[image]

Any body knows any hint about what can be happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the react developer tools browser extension try disabling it, this resolved the issue for me.

React Version: 18.2.0

React Developer Tools Version: 4.25.0

Comment: Thank you so much, It works, maybe is not the best solution since I can not use the devtools but I rather have console.logs!